# How to array.splice from both ends simultaneously in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do you splice from both ends of an array either simultaneously or sequentially such that "leftsplice" number of fields are spliced from left and "rightsplice" number of fields are spliced from original array not the one after doing leftsplicing. Any tips?

```
  const [skillname,setSkillName] = useState(["Engineering", "Product", "Organization", "Business", "Market", "Customer"]);
```

```
    setSkillName(skillname => skillname.splice(0,leftsplice))
    let temp=-5+leftsplice;
    setSkillName(skillname => skillname.splice(temp, rightsplice))
```

This is doing only leftsplicing.
PS: leftsplice, rightsplice are working as desired. I console.logged them

Comment: Don't mutate objects that are stored in the state.  So don't splice the array at all. Use `slice` three times to get three new arrays instead.

Comment: This is quite similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately maybe even a duplicate.

Comment: and restrain from using hardcoded numbers, where does the -5 come from, what is it related to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in splicing is okay, but you should only use `setSkillName` after both leftsplice and rightsplice is done by saving it on a temporary variable, I haven't tested this code below but it is answering the question "How to splice both at the same time from a state" :

```
function whatever() {
  let tempSkillName = [...skillname]
  tempSkillName = tempSkillName.splice(0,leftsplice))
  let temp=-5+leftsplice;
  tempSkillName = tempSkillName.splice(temp, rightsplice))
  setSkillName(tempSkillName)
}
```